Reaction entropies of lithium-ion electrodes
I'm looking for lithium-ion electrode materials with good thermogalvanic properties for heat harvesting. As a sort of pre-screening effort, I am looking for information about the entropy change of various chemical reactions involving lithium ions and some electrode material, preferably in non-aqueous solvents (e.g. the molar reaction entropy of 3Li+ + Li4Ti5O12 + 3e- --> Li7Ti5O12 is about 100 J/mol K). However, I'm struggling to find some good resources for this. Most work seems to focus on different types of materials.
Could anyone recommend a good resource with reaction entropies of various lithium-insertion processes? This need not only be electrodes that are currently used in lithium-ion batteries, but may also be alloying electrodes and the likes.
Thank you so much!
